# Getting Value from DateTimePicker Bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

How do i get the value of a calender from my ajax and send it to a php script. I've tried most of the other threads about this but nothing has worked.

This is my PHP script which spawns the picker:

```
$output_string .="<td id=\"start$count\">\n";
$output_string .="<div class='input-group date'>\n";
$output_string .="<input type='text' class=\"form-control\" id='datetimepicker$count'>\n";
$output_string .="<span class=\"input-group-addon\">\n";
$output_string .="<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-calendar\"></span>\n";
$output_string .="</span>\n";
$output_string .="</div>\n";
$output_string .="</td>\n";
```

Here is the AJAX i'm using to start off another PHP script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $("#run1").click(function(){
        var filename = $("#filename1").text();
        var start_time = $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker("getDate");
            $.ajax({
                url: "launch.php",
                type:"POST",
                data: {"value1": filename, "value2":start_time},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(responce){
                    $("#output").html(responce);
                    } // End of success function of ajax form
                }); // End of ajax call
            });
</script>
```

Edit:

I use loops to generate a table. In the table are datetimepickers. The PHP also generates the AJAX which send the value to launch.php. But for some reason the value of the datetimepicker is either nothing or "undefined".

Full PHP script:

```
<?php

include_once "connectdb.php";

$tbquery = "select * from case_in order by created_time DESC";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $tbquery);
    $output_string ="<table id=\"table\" class=\"table table-striped\"\n";
    $output_string .="<thead>\n";
    $output_string .="<tr>\n";
    $output_string .="<th>File Name</th>\n";
    $output_string .="<th>Created</th>\n";
    $output_string .="<th>Start Time</th>\n";
    $output_string .="<th></th>\n";
    $output_string .="</tr>\n";
    $output_string .="</thead>\n";
    $output_string .="<tbody>\n";
    $output_string .="<tr>\n";
    $count = 0;
foreach ($results as $table) {
    $output_string .="<tr>\n";
    $output_string .="<td id=\"filename$count\">$table[file_name]</td>\n";
    $output_string .="<td id=\"created$count\">$table[created_time]</td>\n";
    $output_string .="<td id=\"start$count\">\n";
    $output_string .="<div class='input-group date'>\n";
    $output_string .="<input type='text' class=\"form-control\" id='datetimepicker$count'>\n";
    $output_string .="<span class=\"input-group-addon\">\n";
    $output_string .="<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-calendar\"></span>\n";
    $output_string .="</span>\n";
    $output_string .="</div>\n";
    $output_string .="</td>\n";
    $output_string .="<td><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn\" id=\"run$count\">Run Job</button>\n";
    $output_string .="</tr>\n";
    $count++;
    }
    $output_string .="</tr>\n";
    $output_string .="</tr>\n";
    $output_string .="</tbody>\n";
    $output_string .="</table>\n";
    $output_string .="<br>";

$n = 0;
while ($n < $count) {
    $output_string .="<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\">\n";
    $output_string .="$(\"#run$n\").click(function(){\n";
    $output_string .="var filename = $(\"#filename$n\").text();\n";
    $output_string .="var start_time = $(\"#datetimepicker$n\").val;\n";
    $output_string .="$.ajax({\n";
    $output_string .="url: \"launch.php\",\n";
    $output_string .="type:\"POST\",\n";
    $output_string .="data: {\"value1\": filename, \"value2\":start_time},\n";
    $output_string .="dataType: \"json\",\n";
    $output_string .="success: function(responce){\n";
    $output_string .="$(\"#output\").html(responce);\n";
    $output_string .="} // End of success function of ajax form\n";
    $output_string .="}); // End of ajax call\n";
    $output_string .="});\n"; 
    $output_string .="</script>\n";
    $output_string .="<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
    $output_string .="$(document).ready(function() {\n";
    $output_string .="$('#datetimepicker$n').datetimepicker({\n";
    $output_string .="defaultDate:new Date()\n";
    $output_string .="});\n";
    $output_string .="});\n";
    $output_string .="</script>\n";
    $n++;
    }

echo json_encode($output_string);

?>
```

Comment: `var start_time = $("#datetimepicker1”).val();` you should use

Comment: `”` is not the same as `"`.

Comment: ive tried that but the variable comes out with "undefined"

Comment: Are you sure that `#datetimepicker1` exists?

Comment: yeah defiantly exists

Comment: Change `”` to `"` here `$("#filename1”).text();` and here `$("#datetimepicker1”).val();`;

Comment: sorry i am using " it was just where i had copied it into my notes before i pasted it on here, but still doesnt work with "

Comment: @KristianCarbonaro you should provide link to the library that you are actually using

Comment: Is multiple `#run` id present in your page?

Comment: yeah there are multiple all spawned through a php loop

Comment: Please show full code with suggestions suggested by people over here.

Comment: Where is this script on your page? Is your `click` event definitely firing?

Comment: yeah the click event defiantly works. Currently in the launch.php it is just echoing back <h3>$filename $start_time</h3>. In the output div the filename spawns but not the start_time.

Comment: full script added

Comment: Change `$output_string .="var start_time = $(\"#datetimepicker$n\").val;\n";` to `$output_string .="var start_time = $(\"#datetimepicker$n\").val();\n";` You Missed to append `()` in `val`.